# ASP Net MVC 3 Application and IIS / IIS Express on windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: iis, deployment, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 web application - it is a set of controllers and views without any DB access at the moment.

In the properties for the WEB App (in vs2010 Sp1) If  I select

Use Visual Studio Development Server defaulting to a port 10905 then the app works great from an f5

If Instead I use local IIS WebServer with Use IIS Express ticked my project url is http://localhost:10905/ and the app works great.

But if I use local IIS WebServer with Use IIS Express NOT ticked my project url is 
http://localhost/TunnelRats then f5 does not work - I literally get a browser popping up with no content displayed just the url address populated.

I created the virtual Directory (using the create directory button) and looked in the IIS Manager
The IIS Manager uses pool ASP.NET v4.0 which has enable 32 bit apps set to true and an integrated pipeline mode.

If I browsse directly from the virtual directory I get the same problem.

Its seems my IIS has a problem where my IIS express does not have a problem running my MVC 3 app.

I used aspnet_regiis -iru to reinstal v4 into IIS with no effect.

Any Ideas
thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

might be that you do not have dynamic content enabled on you IIS.
Easiest way to set up IIS for asp.net  this days is to use  [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)

Comment: Web Installation Failed for IIS configuration 
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS 7.5 component install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Creating IIS 7.0 unattended setup file: F:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5536.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting IIS unattended setup: F:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Waiting for process: 5228 - F:\Windows\sysnative\pkgmgr.exe
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Unattended setup returned '-2146498529'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Directory Browsing done install completed